# How do I change the control of the account in React and NodeJS from email to _userid

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a react, NodeJS application for a movie review webpage where the user log in using email. His/her profile info would then link to this email address. However, I would like to change the extraction of the profile information. Instead of linking to this email address, which the user could change, to a particular userid instead (which is unique) and would not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Retreive user by its Email
for example :

```
var mail= "user@email.com"
service.get('/users/' + mail).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: i presume the /users/ is the userid?

Comment: no the users i the route ( like localhost300/users that will display the users . so if you look for  localhost300/users/user@mail.com for example it will give you back all the information about that user and you can then just take its id